# Reading info from Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am learning about dictionaries, and lost in this problem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<A, B> dict = new Dictionary<A, B>();
        A a = new A { A1 = 1, A2 = 2 };
        B b = new B { B1 = 3, B2 = "foo" };
        dict.Add(a, b);
        A c = new A { A1 = 1, A2 = 2 };

        Console.WriteLine($"dict.ContainsKey(a): {dict.ContainsKey(a)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"dict.ContainsKey(c): {dict.ContainsKey(c)}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

```
class A
{
    public int A1 { get; set; }
    public int A2 { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public int B1 { get; set; }
    public string  B2 { get; set; }
}
```

output for this code is:

```
dict.ContainsKey(a): True
dict.ContainsKey(c): False
```

What I want to achieve is get the value of `B2`, based on the parameters `A1` and `A2`. I was hoping that `dict.ContainsKey(c)` returned `true`, but it does not for some reason.

I could do something like this, which returns `foo`, but that seems to be overkill ?:

```
(from f in dict.Keys where f.A1==1 && f.A2==2 select dict[f].B2).First()
```

How can I get the value for `B2`, If I know a value for `A1` and `A2` ?

Comment: while a and c share the same values, they are _different objects_, with different references. `a!=c`. that is what you described as "some reason"

Comment: It's false because classes in C# are reference types, and while `a` and `c` have the same values (i.e A1 and A2 are the same) they are not the same instance, which is what's checked by default. If you want to you can implement a [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-5.0) which equates `A` with its values and pass a new instance of that to the Dictionary constructor

Comment: while a and c share the same value but reference isn't same

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a9rOds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing *custom* classes, you should explain .net how to do it with a help of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.
If you don't do it, .net will compare *references*, not *values*. In your case it can be

```
class A {
  public int A1 { get; set; }
  public int A2 { get; set; }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
    (obj is A other) && (A1 == other.A1) && (A2 == other.A2); 
  
  public override int GetHashCode() => unchecked((A1 << 16) ^ A2); 

  // For debugging
  public override string ToString() => $"A1 = {A1}; A2 = {A2}";
}
```

Now

```
 Dictionary<A, B> dict = new Dictionary<A, B>() {
   {new A { A1 = 1, A2 = 2 }, new B { B1 = 3, B2 = "foo" }},
 };

 A c = new A { A1 = 1, A2 = 2 };

 if (dict.ContainsKey(c))
   Console.WriteLine($"Contains {c}");
 else
   Console.WriteLine($"Doesn't contains {c}");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a class, which implements the `IEqualityComparer` to define how to compare keys. You want to compare them based on their properties rather than their references.

```
class AValueComparer : IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A x, A y) => x.A1 == y.A1 && x.A2 == y.A2;
    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] A obj) => HashCode.Combine(obj.A1, obj.A2);
}
```

Then all you need is to connect this comparer to your dictionary.

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    //Arrange
    var dict = new Dictionary<A, B>(new AValueComparer());
    var a = new A { A1 = 1, A2 = 2 };
    var b = new B { B1 = 3, B2 = "foo" };
    dict.Add(a, b);
    var c = new A { A1 = 1, A2 = 2 };

    //Act
    var doesAExist = dict.ContainsKey(a);
    var doesCExist = dict.ContainsKey(c);

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(doesAExist, doesCExist);
}
```

Comment: I'd rename the class to something more indicative of it's purpose, something like `AValueComparer`, but yeah, this is how to do it

Comment: @MindSwipe Yes, it make sense. I've renamed.

Comment: This is comparing two boolean values ?

Comment: @Luuk Do you mean test? Yes, `Assert.Equal` compares two `bool` variables.

Comment: If I'm not missing something, this doesn't work: you need a GetHashCode implementation returning the same hash for _Equals_ objects, which the default GetHashCode does not. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aw1Xsn) an example

Comment: OK, `Assert` (and using (automatic)testing in C# did not pass the learning stage....    This means, that I am having this error: "Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'FactAttribute' could not be found ...."

Comment: @Luuk `FactAttribute` is a part of the [xunit testing framework](https://xunit.net/). You don't have to use it at all, I've just used it for demonstrate that the expected behaviour is achieved by the `AValueComparer`

Comment: @GianPaolo Yes, that's correct. I've just posted the code without actually giving a try :( I've updated. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

It's false because classes in C# are reference types, and while `a` and `c` have the same values (i.e `A1` and `A2` are the same) they are not the same instance, which is what's checked by default. If you want to you can implement a IEqualityComparer which equates A with its values and pass a new instance of that to the Dictionary constructor